# Replace img src but have loading graphic display while image is downloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that swaps some fairly large images in and out. There are too many to preload when the page initially loads so that is not an option. So what I need to do is load them as they are requested by the user. Right now I'm using jQuery to replace the `img`'s `src`. This works fine but the images I am loading can be around 500KB and it looks bad as they paint down the screen as they are downloading. What I'd like to do is pop a loading gif on the page when the image is in the process of loading then have the loading gif disappear once the image is loaded. I'm struggling to find a way to do that though. Here is the JS/jQuery code that I have that just replaces the `src`.

```
var product = "bowl";
var image = "dog.jpg"; //this is actually pulled from a data attribute, but its just hardcoded here for an example

$("#images img[data-product="+product+"]").attr("src", "/img/tablesetting/"+image);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I made a working jsfiddle showing this principle
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/c72RT/4/

I recently needed to do the same thing. Basically I wrapped the image in a container div. within the container I've added a span element with my ajax loader gif embedded. this span has to be hidden initially but gets visible when an ajax request is made. The span gets removed when the image is fully loaded.

before ajax call

```
 $('#your_image_container').find('span').show();
```

on success

```
 $('#your_image').attr('src', 'your/image/url').load(function() {

      $('#your_image_container').find('span').fadeOut(); 

  });
```

I made a jsfiddle showing this principle

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/c72RT/4/

Comment: Bind the load event before you set the src, otherwise this will fail when the image is cached in some browsers.

Comment: or you just can add a dummy variable to the image url. see updated fiddle

Comment: @kasperTaeymans if you add a dummy variable, then the image will get loaded even if it's cached :(

Answer (score 1):

Preload the image.

```
var product = "bowl";
var imageSrc = "dog.jpg";
var imgEl = $("#images img[data-product="+product+"]");
// show loading graphic only if it's needed
var timer = setTimeout(function(){
    imgEl.attr("src", "/img/loading.gif");
},50);

// preload image
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    imgEl.attr("src",imageSrc);
}
img.src = imageSrc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$img.attr("src", newImage);

if (!$img.get(0).complete) {
    $img
        .hide()
        .after("<img src=throbber>")
        .on("load", function () {
             $(this).show().next().remove();
         });
}
```